# 2001 Ford Expedition Eddie Bauer only blows cold and hot air

Tags: ford, heat, expedition

I have a 2001 Ford Expedition Eddie Bauer that o ly blows cold air at 60 and hot at 65 and up. It is almost like the car always thinks it is 61-64 inside.

Comment: So many unknowns, when you post a question on stack exchange, post what your problem is, what you recently tried to do and how you would like us to help, when you say 60 and 65 I have no idea what you're talking about, ambient temp, coolant temp, cabin temp, a 2001 doesn't have an auto adjuster to the inside temperature. No thermostat unless you manually installed one to auto adjust

Comment: If you put your ac on max, because I assume you're talking about your air conditioning, does it blow cold ? Yes good, if you put your ac on regular cold air does it blow out warm or take awhile, time to buy a dryer, orifice tube, oil, manifold gauges, freeon, vacuum pump for the mercury, and manifold gauges, o-ring, and test the compressor. Cause its probably about time for an overhaul

Comment: I have the same issue- I will explain more what he means- the climate control- (It is an electronic readout) on manual or automatic will blow cold air when set on 60 degrees when you switch it to the next notch up 65 degrees it goes straight to full hot- no stages in between and no warm just cold or hot. We just had our front heater core replaced (had it bypassed for a couple of months) Now the unit is doing this. The mechanic replaced the blend door motor no change (he didn't charge us for it fortunately) still just hot or cold. The rear heat is not blowing anything but cold. (That may be a s